# Fortran 77 DO label also used by IF/GOTO

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have an old fortran 77 code, which I like to keep unchanged as much as possible. Since `gfortran` gives the loop warnings, I was thinking of changing the non-block loops to block mode. But then I realised that some `GOTO` statements use the same loop labels as well. Now I am not sure how the compiler behaves with regard to the statements *that follow the labels*.

So my question is whether I can "modernise" this example code:

```
      INTEGER i
      DO 30 i = 1, 14
      IF <SOME CONDITION> GOTO 30
      <SOME COMMANDS HERE>
  30  WRITE(*,*) i
      <SOME FOLLOWING STATEMENTS>
```

To this one:

```
      INTEGER i
      DO 30 i = 1, 14
      WRITE(*,*) i
      IF <SOME CONDITION> GOTO 30    
      <SOME COMMANDS HERE>  
  30  CONTINUE  
      <SOME FOLLOWING STATEMENTS>
```

Or even this one:

```
      INTEGER i
      DO i = 1, 14
      WRITE(*,*) i
      IF <SOME CONDITION> GOTO 30    
      <SOME COMMANDS HERE>  
      END DO
  30  <SOME FOLLOWING STATEMENTS>
```

In this latter form, I am not sure whether the label should go to the `END DO` or to the following statement?

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran]. You can add a version tag if relevant.

Comment: In your initial version the test+goto is completely useless, as the next executed instruction is always `write(*,*) i`. In the second version the test is useless as well

Comment: If changing the code, the answer seems to be "use`cycle` or `exit`" rather than worrying about clarity of exact interpretation by compiler and other readers of the code. Is there a real reason to retain `go to`?

Comment: @PierU sorry, I forgot to write that there are some statements between the test and loop end. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @francescalus The code is in reality very very ugly, with hundreds of labeled nested loops and GOTOs etc. We just don't want to touch it as much as possible, just remove loop warnings. Because the code has been used many many years, all people using it over years confirm its calculation is good AND the code is written by my own boss in his youth! :-)

Comment: If you want to use the code and eliminate loop warning and you're using gfortran, then use the following options `-std=legacy -w`.

Comment: thanks @steve. That indeed does the job and suppresses the warnings. But I am also curious myself to understand, if I choose the last variant, would I need to place the label near `END DO` or near the following statement.

Comment: See the answer from @PierU.  If you're going to touch the code to avoid a (hamrless) warning, then you should consider bringing it into the 21st century.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line with the loop termination label belongs to the loop (i.e. the instruction is executed at each iteration), meaning that in your initial version the loop is always executed until i=15. Consequently, your 3rd version is wrong. The second version is OK.

But if you want to modernize the code, you may write instead:

```
      INTEGER i
      DO i = 1, 14
         IF (.NOT.<SOME CONDITION>) THEN    
            <SOME COMMANDS HERE>
         END IF
         WRITE(*,*) i
      END DO  
      <SOME FOLLOWING STATEMENTS>
```

or alternatively

```
      INTEGER i
      DO i = 1, 14
         WRITE(*,*) i
         IF (<SOME CONDITION>) CYCLE ! directly starts the next iteration
         <SOME COMMANDS HERE>
      END DO  
      <SOME FOLLOWING STATEMENTS>
```

Comment: just one final question on this: would my 3rd version be as good, if I'd place the label on the line with `END DO` ?

Comment: @xaratustra why not trying :) ?